# Zabbix scheduledreport: test failed Cannot connect to web service couldn't connect to server

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

I am using zabbix to monitor my workplace infra, everything works fine. Now, I want to start generating reports. Although I followed everything as it is on the doc I still get this error:

```
Report generating test failed.

Cannot connect to web service: couldn't connect to server
```

​

Zabbix server (6.0 LTS), the database (mysql) and the web gui are all installed on the same VM on centos 8 stream without gui. I access, manage and administrate from my computer through ssh to the server and access the web gui through https://server_ip/zabbix. All traffic needed is allowed on firewall. I installed google-chrome-stable and the zabbix-web-service and configured it as it says (http://server_ip:10053/report). In the zabbix gui I added the Frontend URL https://server_ip/zabbix. I went through all the combinations of @ip, localhost, 127.0.0.1 between the server and the web-service and still get the same error, I also tried chromium and nothing.

From the server I tried `curl -v http://server-ip:10053/report` and I got

```
*   Trying ip@...

* TCP_NODELAY set

* Connected to ip@ (ip@) port 10053 (#0)

GET /report HTTP/1.1

Host: ip@:10053

User-Agent: curl/7.61.1

 Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Content-Type: application/problem+json

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Date: Tue, 07 Feb 2023 14:35:16 GMT

Content-Length: 38

{"detail":"Method is not supported."}

* Connection #0 to host ip@ left intact
```

Normally it should work because everything is on the same VM!

Answer (score 0):

Hope I am not too late to reply and error is resolved now.
I had similar errors with new installed zabbix and not sure what resolved it but I am listing my working config for your perusal. I would suggest to check/share logs from zabbix server and web service log files for further investigation.

**OS** - 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-60-generic x86_64)

**Browser** -

- ungoogled-chromium-common/now 100.0.4896.127-1
- ungoogled-chromium/now 100.0.4896.127-1

**Web portal Frontend URL** - http://localhost/

**Zabbix_server.conf** -

- StartReportWriters=3
- WebServiceURL=http://localhost:10053/report

**Zabbix_web_service.conf** -

- AllowedIP=127.0.0.1
- ListenPort=10053